# Most Efficient Way to Find Common Item Between Arbitrary Number of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization, unique

I need to be able to find a common item between an arbitrary number of arrays. For example, let's say there's an object like this:

```
var obj = {
  a: [ 15, 23, 36, 49, 104, 211 ],
  b: [ 9, 12, 23 ],
  c: [ 11, 17, 18, 23, 38 ],
  d: [ 13, 21, 23, 27, 40, 85]
};
```

I'd need to determine the common item between each of these arrays. (In this case, 23).

My solution is to find the shortest array, and iterate through each item in it, checking the index of the other arrays.

```
var shortest = {};
var keys = [];
for ( var key in obj ) {

  if ( obj.hasOwnProperty( key ) && Array.isArray( obj[ key ] ) ) {
    keys.push( key );

    if ( !shortest.hasOwnProperty( 'length' ) || obj[ key ].length < shortest.length ) {
      shortest.name = key;
      shortest.length = obj[ key ].length;
    }
  }
}



var res = obj[ shortest.name ].filter(function ( v ) {

  for ( var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++ ) {

    if ( obj[ keys[ i ] ].indexOf( v ) === -1 ) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
};
```

However, this seems enormously inefficient, and I'm trying to determine if there's a better way, preferably without having to loop through things multiple times.

Comment: So all the arbitrary arrays happen to be sorted in your sample code. Is this just happenstance or is it a fact?

Comment: @Quirk Happenstance. I believe the data source will return sorted, but I'm hesitant to count on it.

Comment: If all the arrays are sorted, then the worst case runtime is probably linear in the sum of their sizes, i.e. `O(n1 + n2 + ...)`

Comment: See [How to calculate intersection of multiple arrays in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37320296/1529630)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076067/finding-matches-between-multiple-javascript-arrays

Comment: But if your code already works, you should ask at codereview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do this in less than `O(N)`, where `N` is the number of items in all arrays. Your current solution is less efficient, since `indexOf` is `O(N)` for each array, and you could run through all of them for each item in the shortest array.

I think a map-based option would be `O(N)`:

```
var counts = {};
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
var arr, el;
for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
    arr = obj[keys[k]];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        el = arr[i];
        if (counts[el] === undefined) {
            // new value, start counting
            counts[el] = 1;
        } else {
            // increment count for this value
            counts[el]++;
            // if we have as many values as keys, we're done
            if (counts[el] === keys.length) {
                return el;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some caveats here:

- This assumes that the elements can be used as object keys (i.e. they can be uniquely converted to strings), and that you don't have some nasty edge cases like `1` and `"1"` in different arrays.
- This assumes the array values are unique for each array.
- This assumes there's only one element in the intersection.

https://jsfiddle.net/xzfa75og/

Comment: You can't do it in less than `O(N)` for sure. You must at least read all the values, and that's already `O(N)`.

Comment: Worst case is always `O(N)`, but you don't have to read all values in the common cases if you know there's only one element in the intersection.

Comment: This seems like it's exactly what I need.

Comment: This solution fails if each one of the array items is not unique. If there are duplicate items in an array it deceives the algorithm by resulting false count.

Comment: @Redu - true, adding to caveats

Answer (score 2):

Another `O(n)` set union solution, coded more functionally.  Elements as object keys caveat still applies although this will return the set (array) of all shared elements in the intersection.

```
function common(o) {
  // Map each of the object key arrays to a set.
  return Object.keys(o).map(function(k) {
    return o[k].reduce(function(a, e) {
      a[e] = 1;
      return a;
    }, {});
  }).reduce(function(a, e) {
    // Perform a set union.
    Object.keys(e).forEach(function(k) {
      if (!a[k]) {
        delete e[k];
      }
    });
    return e;
  })
}

var obj = {
  a: [ 15, 23, 36, 49, 104, 211 ],
  b: [ 9, 12, 23 ],
  c: [ 11, 17, 18, 23, 38 ],
  d: [ 13, 21, 23, 27, 40, 85]
};

common(obj);
```

Comment: This don't look like O(n). Your O(n) time is done when you map the  Object.keys into objects and then you do more reduces and forEach operation. Looks to me like O(2n). Plus this algorithm also fails for the duplicate entries such as, in case each array has two or more items as 23 this will find only one of them.

Comment: Yes, this does set intersection. If you want to count multiples (i.e. bags), you can keep count in the accumulator (replace `a[e] = 1` with `a[e]++`, initializing as needed) and take `min(a[k], e[k])` on `reduce`.  `O(n)` simply means linear asymptotic growth.  Using this notation, `O(2n) = O(n)` as both are linear.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this job by an invention of `Array.prototype.intersect()`. It won't fail when there are duplicate items in the array. If you have same item duplicated in each array you will get the duplicate in the intersection as it should be. Let's see how it will work

```js
Array.prototype.intersect = function(...a) {
      return [this,...a].reduce((p,c) => p.filter(e => c.includes(e)));
    };
var obj = {
           a: [ 15, 23, 36, 49, 104, 211 ],
           b: [ 9, 12, 23 ],
           c: [ 11, 17, 18, 23, 38 ],
           d: [ 13, 21, 23, 27, 40, 85]
          },
   arrs = Object.keys(obj).map(e => obj[e]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrs.pop().intersect(...arrs))); // take the last one out to invoke the method over the rest
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution in ES5 with a temporary object in **O(n)**.

```js
var obj = { a: [15, 23, 36, 49, 104, 211], b: [9, 12, 23, 15], c: [11, 17, 18, 23, 38], d: [13, 21, 23, 27, 40, 85] },
    result = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (o) {
        return function (r, k, i) {
            var t = o;
            o = Object.create(null);
            return obj[k].filter(function (a) {
                return (!i || t[a]) && (o[a] = true);
            });
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is the only algorithm that does the job in O(n) within the given answers. I guess i have to modify my `Array.prototype.intersect()` to utilize the filter callback as your method even though `includes()` simply looks cooler.

Comment: You should probably re-consider your romance with Edge again. I have no idea how come Edge applied for a pull request to Node. Pretty much nothing works with Edge including destructuring, spread operator, etc etc god knows what else. I think the best is Firefox (basically i appreciate their amazing documentation and helps to the community) and i haven't seen anything not working at FF. Chrome is OK but has just started with V50 to be able to convert a nodeList into an array by spread operator like `myArr = [...nodeList]`. But why Edge..?