# Intersect arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I `INTERSECT` ***N*** arrays in Javascript at a reasonably fast time?

Ie.

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
arr2 = [1,2,3,4];
arr3 = [4];
arr4 = [4,5];
```

**Result:** `[4]`

Comment: They seem to be asking about the intersection of the lists.

Comment: rather than revinvent the wheel, check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320296/how-to-calculate-intersection-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript-and-what-does-e

Comment: What exactly is NJOIN?  Do you mean intersection?

Comment: Woops! Was thinking of SQL

Comment: In the future, if you mean to respond to a specific person's comment, then use put @username in your comment.  That's the ONLY way they will get notified that you've done something you want them to see.  Otherwise, they'll never see your comment.

Answer (score 3):

You could take an intersection function for common elements with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
function common(a, b) {
    return b.filter(Set.prototype.has.bind(new Set(a)));
}

console.log([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [4], [4, 5]].reduce(common));
```

Comment: Is this "reasonably fast" as the OP asked?  It creates a `new Set()` a lot.

Comment: for the given data, it is fast to write ... o_O

Comment: Nina, can you explain this bit: Set.prototype.has.bind(new Set(a))

Comment: @jamesemanon, what i want, is to take a function as callback. in this case `has` from `Set`, but it is not possible to use `new Set([...]).has`, because it returns an error `Set.prototype.has: 'this' is not a Set object`. therefore i took the prototype and with `bind` it takes a set as `this`. voila

Comment: imho, that is pretty clever

Answer (score 3):

I would simply use `filter()` and `includes()` unless I knew my arrays were going to be very large. This runs "reasonably fast" and is probably faster than creating a bunch of sets when you will be joining a lot of normal-sized arrays, however for fewer, very large arrays, the `new Set()` could prove faster :

```js
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
let arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5];
let arr3 = [4];
let arr4 = [4,5];

let r = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4].reduce((a, c) => a.filter(i => c.includes(i)))
console.log(r)
```