# How to put common strings from two different arrays to another array

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

I am studying Javascript, for loop, and trying to put the same elements from two different arrays to another new array. 
It will print two common elements when I put 'console.log()' outside of For loop, However, if I put 'return console.log()' in if statement, it won't work properly(it shows only [ 'Ray' ].)

I would like to know the difference between them.

I will leave two codes for you. 
Thank you so much for your help.

---

```
//code1
let bobsFollowers = ['Natalia', 'Ray', 'Kay', 'Clau'];
let tinasFollowers = ['Ray', 'Yama', 'Kay'];
let mutualFollowers = [];

for(let i = 0; i< bobsFollowers.length; i++){
  for (let j = 0; j< tinasFollowers.length; j++){
    if (bobsFollowers[i] === tinasFollowers[j]){
       mutualFollowers.push(bobsFollowers[i])

    }
  }
}

 console.log(mutualFollowers)//output: [ 'Ray', 'Kay' ]


//code2
let bobsFollowers = ['Natalia', 'Ray', 'Kay', 'Clau'];
let tinasFollowers = ['Ray', 'Yama', 'Kay'];
let mutualFollowers = [];

for(let i = 0; i< bobsFollowers.length; i++){
  for (let j = 0; j< tinasFollowers.length; j++){
    if (bobsFollowers[i] === tinasFollowers[j]){
       mutualFollowers.push(bobsFollowers[i])
return console.log(mutualFollowers)     
    }
  }
}// output: [ 'Ray' ]
```

Comment: maybe you are interested in some more advance tackling of this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320296/how-to-calculate-intersection-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript-and-what-does-e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `return` keyword breaks the current function execution and returns a value. If you use it in the loop, it will break it as soon as it's executed. This is basically the direct reason for that.

More explanation:
If you do `return console.log(mutualFollowers);`, then the `console.log()` is evaluated first, and the result of that is passed to the `return` which returns it from the current function. The result of `console.log()` is `undefined` so your main function will also return `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian. I am new to Javascript, and this answer really helped me to understand this problem. your extra info, it's really good to know, Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help ;) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

well of course... `return` statements stops the execution of the function you're in, meaning it also breaks the `for` loop you're in.

In your case, it gets to the `return` only after finding the first mutual follower, which is `Ray`, so it breaks the function and prints only `['ray']`.

BTW, because your return is on the `console.log()`, it actually return out of the function the result of the `console.log()` operation, which is undefined.

Comment: Thank you, Gibor!

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `return` exits the current function, in javascript, but not only. Most programming languages work like this.

So when it processes 'Ray', it quits the function without processing the next ones.

Comment: Thank you, Vincent!