# How can I find similar objects in multiple array javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, filter

**Facing an issue in filter. New in javascript. I can explain the problem with an example. Here is an example I have three arrays of different size and objects I want to get the common object of them all**

```
var arrays = [
    [
      {
        "id": "5",
        "Name" : "Actor 5"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": "5",
        "Name" : "Actor 5"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "Name" : "Actor 6"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": "3",
        "Name" : "Actor 3"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "Name" : "Actor 4"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "Name" : "Actor 5"
      }
    ]
];
```

**The answer should be**

```
[
      {
        "id": "5",
        "Name" : "Actor 5"
      }
]
```

I tried:

```
var result = arrays.shift().filter(function(v.Name) {
  return arrays.every(function(a) {
    return a.indexOf(v.Name) !== -1;
  });
});
```

Comment: @JaromandaX He has one array containing 3 nested arrays of objects.

Comment: For ideas look through answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320296/how-to-calculate-intersection-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript-and-what-does-e

Comment: @JaromandaX One array containing 3 arrays in itself

Comment: @Alijutt - thank you for re-pointing out my mistake - I'll remove my comments now

Comment: I tried filter but couldn't get the desired answer can anyone of you please help me in that

Comment: filter sounds like a good plan - show what you did so we can point out the mistake

Comment: `var result = arrays.shift().filter(function(v.Name) {
    return arrays.every(function(a) {
        return a.indexOf(v.Name) !== -1;
    });
});`

Comment: @JaromandaX above is the code that I used to get the results

Comment: `a.indexOf(v.Name)` won't work, since `a` is an array of objects, not strings.

Comment: Use `a.find(el => el.Name = v.Name)`

Comment: `function(v.Name)` is invalid syntax, it should be `function (v)`

Comment: @Barmar how I should change this?

Comment: so, just the Name has to match? not the id? easy: `arrays[0].filter(a=>arrays.slice(1).every(b=>b.some(c=>c.Name===a.Name)));`

Comment: @JaromandaX We can match either the name or the id

Comment: your code doesn't attempt to do that ... so it's OR not AND? in other words `arrays[0].filter(a=>arrays.slice(1).every(b=>b.some(c=>c.id===a.id||c.Name===a.Name)));`

Comment: `var result = arrays.shift().filter(function(v) {
    return arrays.every(function(a) {
        return a.find(el => el.Name = v.Name);
    });
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `reduce` to find the duplicated object.

```js
var array = [
  [{
    "id": "5",
    "Name": "Actor 5"
  }],
  [{
      "id": "5",
      "Name": "Actor 5"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "Name": "Actor 6"
    }
  ],
  [{
      "id": "3",
      "Name": "Actor 3"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "Name": "Actor 4"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "Name": "Actor 5"
    }
  ]
];

array.reduce((prev, curr, index, currentArray) => {
  try {
    for (let arr of currentArray) {
      if (`[${JSON.stringify(curr[0])}]` === JSON.stringify(arr)) {
        console.log(curr[0])
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can't put `v.Name` in a parameter list, it can only contain variable names or destructuring patterns. You should put `v` in the parameter list, then use `v.Name` in the function body. Or you could use the destructuring pattern `{Name}`.
- You can't use `a.IndexOf(v.Name)`, because `a` is an array of objects, but `v.Name` is a string. Use `a.some(el => el.Name = v.Name)` to test if the name is in any of the objects in the array.

```js
var arrays = [
  [{
    "id": "5",
    "Name": "Actor 5"
  }],
  [{
      "id": "5",
      "Name": "Actor 5"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "Name": "Actor 6"
    }
  ],
  [{
      "id": "3",
      "Name": "Actor 3"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "Name": "Actor 4"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "Name": "Actor 5"
    }
  ]
];

var result = arrays.shift().filter(v =>
  arrays.every(subarray => subarray.some(el => el.Name == v.Name)));

console.log(result);
```